# Error after creating play-hibernate template

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I've created a Play! Framework 2.4 project using play-hibernate template through activator. When it finished building the project, I went to its root directory and ran the project. When I accessed it through the browser (localhost:9000), it returned an error:

```
package utils does not exist
In path/projectName/Global.java:3

1import play.Application;

2import play.GlobalSettings;

3import utils.PlayUtils;
```

That's odd, since there is a folder utils along with Global.java, with a Java class PlayUtils inside it. A bug, maybe?

Has anybody experienced anything like that?

Thank you very much for your time!

edit:
auL5agoi asked for the link to this template, and here it goes: https://github.com/ldaume/play-hibernate#master
Thank you for participating!

Comment: Could you link that template please? A wild guess, check in the conf/application.conf file if something is commented out which you might need. At the end of the day this also looks very useless, I mean you could just comment out all that stuff(Globalsettings, PlayUtils), because all you need is the hibernate stuff in build.sbt and the META-INF/persistence.xml